# Горизонтальная прокрутка по ходу вертикальной прокрутки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, мышь

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```js
var $hor = $("#horizontal");

$("body").css('padding-bottom', $hor[0].scrollWidth - $hor.outerWidth());

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var top = $(document).scrollTop();
  var lim = $hor.position().top - $hor[0].scrollLeft - ($(window).height() - $hor.outerHeight()) / 2;
  var width = $hor[0].scrollWidth - $hor.outerWidth();
  var delta = Math.min(Math.max(top - lim, 0), width);
  
  $hor[0].scrollLeft = delta;
  $("body").css({'padding-top': delta, 'padding-bottom': width - delta});
});
```

```css
#horizontal {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 7em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p id="horizontal">Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано.</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
```

А вот так можно сделать справа налево, как на той странице:

```js
var $hor = $("#horizontal");

$("body").css('padding-bottom', $hor[0].scrollLeft = $hor[0].scrollWidth - $hor.outerWidth());

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var top = $(document).scrollTop();
  var width = $hor[0].scrollWidth - $hor.outerWidth();
  var lim = $hor.position().top - (width - $hor[0].scrollLeft) - ($(window).height() - $hor.outerHeight()) / 2;
  var delta = Math.min(Math.max(top - lim, 0), width);
  
  $hor[0].scrollLeft = width - delta;
  $("body").css({'padding-top': delta, 'padding-bottom': width - delta});
});
```

```css
#horizontal {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#horizontal > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<div id="horizontal"><div style="background:silver">Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано.</div><div style="background:antiquewhite">Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано.</div></div>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
<p>Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это сделано. На примере этой страницы - http://recruit.aif.ru/#id=3 Во время вертикальной прокрутки страницы как колесиком мыши, так и скроллингом, когда доходим до блока с узкой горизонтальной фотографией, страница останавливается с центрированием фотографии по вертикали страницы, и начинается горизонтальная прокрутка контента внутри этой фотографии, после чего продолжается вертикальная прокрутка страницы. Поиском пользовался, информации море, куча разных плагинов, но что конкретно в этом фокусе, не могу понять. Предполагаю, что здесь не нужен какой-то огромный или объемный плагин. Может быть я ошибаюсь. Хотел бы увидеть это на каком-нибудь конкретном минимальном примере, где четко будет виден код скрипта и стиль и сама разметка html, чтобы понять саму логику. Буду очень благодарен вам за примеры!</p>
```

Заметил, что при некоторых размерах наблюдается дрожание на 1px. Подозреваю, что это связано с округлениями и может быть устранено дополнительной проверкой.

Comment: @LADYX, там прокрутка в другую сторону. Добавил пример.

Comment: @LADYX, указать ширину? А вообще, вероятно, надо чинить слайдер?

Comment: @LADYX, задай отдельный вопрос с [mcve] и дай ссылку.