# Бегущая строка при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Друзья, всем привет! как сделать вот такую бегущую строку при скролле?
То есть, строка должна полностью прокрутиться до конца сайта.
Смотреть фото и сайт (пример):
https://liginc.co.jp/works/detail/ateam/

Заранее огромное спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540832/178988

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот примерная реализация того что вы хотите.

Делаем вот что. Взяли длину фиксированного элемента, и высоту страницы. Делим длину на высоту, для того что бы понять при скролле на `1px` сколько процентов должен двигаться наш элемент на лева. Ну и уже нам осталось обработать событие `scroll`.

Там уже вычисляем сколько пикселей должен продвигаться наш элемент. Для этого умножаем текущий `scrollTop` к ранее вычисленному `slide_left` и берем отрицательное значение (отрицательное для того что бы дать стилю `left` нашего элемента и продвигать его на лево).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var w_height= $(this).height();
  var slide_width = $('.fixed_bottom').width();
  var slide_left = slide_width/w_height;
  $(window).scroll(function(e){
    var f_left = slide_left*$(this).scrollTop()*-1;
    $('.fixed_bottom').css({left: f_left});
    
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  height:800px;
}
.fixed_bottom{
  position: fixed;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="fixed_bottom">Здесь наш очень длинный текст. Совсем длинный.))))))))))))))</footer>
```

Ну а это второй вариант. Все те же вычисления, но это уже с анимацией перехода.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var w_height= $(this).height();
  var slide_width = $('.fixed_bottom').width();
  var slide_left = slide_width/w_height;

  $(window).scroll(function(e){
    var f_left = slide_left*$(this).scrollTop()*-1;

    $('.fixed_bottom').animate({
        left: f_left
    }, 90);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  height:800px;
}
.fixed_bottom{
  position: fixed;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="fixed_bottom">
  Здесь наш очень длинный текст. Совсем длинный.))))))))))))))</footer>
```

Comment: А не знаете почему в FireFox эти сниппеты работают, а в Chrome нет?

Comment: @maxwell не понял что не работает в `chrome`?

Comment: У меня в хром не выполнялся код. Проблема была во включенных расширениях)

Comment: @maxwell Удивили меня, я использую `chrome`, и в нем всегда это работало.

Comment: @StackOverflow, вопрос такой, что происходит в первом примере, понятно, будь другом, скажи такую вещь. Если второй пример реализовать на чистом JS, то как реализовать аналог animate-JQ...  Прошу без кода, хочу сам  поковыряться, просто логику намекни...

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо! Просто и интересно! Мне надо было встроить такое в модуль Joomla. И так, чтобы тект перемещался со скролингом вверх-вниз вместе со страницей и одновременно лево-право. Поменял fixed на relative и все.