# Почему при работе с скроллом задают left или top с меняюшимися значениями

Tags: javascript, css, прокрутка, слайдер

Почему при работе с скроллом пишут элементу, который должен скроллиться `position:absolute;` и меняют ему значения `top` или `left`, а не используют к примеру `elem.scrollBy(x, y)`.

Наверно сложно понять, вот примеры сайтов(загляните в код и увидете меняюшиеся значения `top` и `left`).

http://demo.select-themes.com/capri12/

https://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/

---

К примеру со скроллом.

https://jsfiddle.net/kcewxf6p/

Comment: судя по примерам нужно не крутить окно, крутит его мышка, а позиционировать элементы относительно прокрученных пикселей (правда это быстрее и плавнее будет работать через transform translate)

Comment: Необязательно использовать скролл на window. Если есть скролл в элементе, то можно на нем вызвать метод и он уже будет прокручиваться

Comment: ну значит вы и сами все понимаете, в чем вопрос то?

Comment: Ну может быть люди делают так, потому что это более оптимизированно, а не знаю так ли это, а чтоб не промахнуться задал вопрос поглобальнее.  Для чего люди так это реализируют(может я чего-то не знаю)

Comment: Ну попробуй сделать так же своим способом, а когда не получится, напишешь ответ, почему. Обрати внимание, что у них полоса прокрутки видима и за неё можно скроллить. Ну и на планшете без колёсика скроллить тоже можно.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550320/178988